# 'No method found' compiler warning for a method inside a #define directive

Tags: objective-c, warnings, c-preprocessor

I have a method DoSomething() *defined* in my AppDelegate.

This is the full implementation of my appDelegate:

```
#import "SampleAppAppDelegate.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define DoSomething()\
NSConnection *conn = [NSConnection connectionWithRegisteredName:@"myConnection" host:nil];\
NSLog(@"Compiler seems to have found the class %@", [NSConnection class]);\


@implementation SampleAppAppDelegate

@synthesize window;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    DoSomething();
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Although the implementation is working fine as expected (the log is recognizing the class)
the compiler is displaying a warning:

```
warning: no '+connectionWithRegisteredName:host:' method found
```

Any ideas how I can solve this issue? 
How can I modify the implementation to get rid of the warning?

Comment: The warning means that no interface has declared a method with a matching selector. You should not be getting it since you imported Foundation. It is probably a bug caused by calling the method from a macro.

Comment: Hard to tell from the code you’ve pasted. A small program containing your macro definition and a single use of that macro builds with no warnings. Try to provide the smallest program that yields the aforementioned warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, you’re targeting iOS. `NSConnection` is not available in the public API for the iOS SDK.

Comment: ah I see now. Thanks for pointing that out. This post also confirms it. http://jitsik.com/wordpress/?p=57  The utility I am writing is to help debugging during development when running from the simulator. I will have to work around it, if i every forget removing this code Apple might reject the app right? need to find away to handle that somehow.

Comment: @Bach I have no experience with using private frameworks. That being said, `NSConnection` is available in the Foundation framework on the simulator SDK, so in theory you could use your code wrapped around #ifdef TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR … #endif, I suppose. And yes, if that code is submitted to Apple, they will reject the app. That #ifdef should take care of it, though, since the submitted app is built targeting the device, not the simulator.